# How to turn following PHP process into AJAX process?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

On my website I give users an option to subscribe to blog authors. Right now it is a php process and requires page refresh each time user clicks "SUBSCRIBE" or "UNSUBSCRIBE" button. I was thinking that it is a time to make this process sort of AJAX based, so when users click "SUBSCRIBE" or "UNSUBSCRIBE" buttons there would be no page refresh, but their subscription arrays would be updated. therefore buttons will change respectively e.g. if user clicks "SUBSCRIBE" button it will change to "UNSUBSCRIBE" and backwards.
The problem is that I never used AJAX before and I can't find useful information to achieve this specific task, because there is a lot of it.
So could anyone suggest how to make this process sort of AJAX, so no page refresh takes place? If possible jQuery based solution would be great.

---

**HTML & PHP for Buttons**

```
//SUBSCRIBE Button
<?php if (($isLogedIN) && ($canSubscribe) && (!$isBlogOwner)) { ?>
<form id="subscribeform" name="subscribeform" method="post" action="blog.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
   <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
<?php } ?>

//UNSUBSCRIBE Button
<?php if (($isLogedIn) && ($canUnSubscribe) && (!$isBlogOwner)) { ?>
<form id ="unsubscribeform" name="unsubscribeform" method="post" action="blog.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
   <input type="submit" name="unsubscribe" value="Unsubscribe" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

---

**PHP to update database records**

```
//Subscribe
if (isset $_POST['subscribe'])){
   //First Update Visitors Subscription Array
   if($subscription_array != ""){
      $subscription_array = "$subscription_array,$blogauthid";
   } else {
      $subscription_array = "$blogauthid";}
   $updateSubscription_array = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET subs='$subscription_array' WHERE id='$reader'") or die (mysql_error());
   //Then Update blog writers subscribers array
   $subArray7 = mysql_query("SELECT subscribers FROM members WHERE id='$blogauthid' LIMIT1");
   while($subrow7=mysql_fetch_array($subArray7)) {subscription_array7 =  $subrow7["subscribers"];}
   if ($subscription_array7 !="") {
       $subscription_array7 = "$subscription_array7,$reader";
   } else {
   $updateSubscription_array7 = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET subscribers='$subscription_array' WHERE id='$blogauthid'") or die (mysql_error());
   header("location: blog.php?id=$blogid");exit();



//Unsubscribe
if (isset($_POST['unsubscribe'])){
   //First Update visitors subscription array
   foreach ($subscription_array2 as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == $blogauthid)
                unset($subscription_array2[$key]);
            }
}
$newSubArray = implode(",", $subscription_array2);
$updateSubscription_array = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET subs='$newSubArray' WHERE id='$reader'") or die (mysql_error());
//Than update blog writers subscription array
$subArray9 = mysql_query("SELECT subscribers FROM members WHERE id='$blogauthid' LIMIT 1");
while($subrow9=mysql_fetch_array($subArray9)) {subscriber_array9 = $subrow9["subscribers"];}
$subscriber_array9b = explode(",", $subscriber_array9);
foreach ($subscribe_array9b as $key9 => $value9) {
         if ($value9 == $reader) {
             unset($subscriber_array9b[$key9]);
         }
}
$newSubArray9 = implode(",", $subscriber_array9b);
$updateblogSubsArray = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET subscribers='$newSubArray9' WHERE id='$blogauthid'") or die (mysql_error());
header ("location: blog.php?id=$blogid");exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be optimized a little, but it's functionality is more clear at each step and it should work. This is Jquery $.post, as requested.

You only need one form element:

```
<form id="subscribeform" name="subscribeform" method="post" action="blog.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
   <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
```

At the bottom of your document, just before the closing body tag, link the jquery library, followed by the script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#subscribeform input:submit').click(function() {
        // $.post is the jquery shorthand method for $.ajax - it always uses POST 
        $.post(
                // url
                'blog.php?id=<?=$id?>',
                // serialized form data to POST
                $('#subscribeform').serialize(),
                // success callback toggles form value
                function(data) {
                    if ($('#subscribeform input:submit').val() == 'Subscribe') {
                        $('#subscribeform input:submit').
                           attr('name','Unsubscribe').val('Unsubscribe');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#subscribeform input:submit').
                           attr('name','Subscribe').val('Subscribe');
                    }
                }
         );
    });
});
```

Comment: will work for unsubscribe too right? I mean the php part uses if isset $_POST["unsubscribe"] , but here we only have one input, that's whats confused me.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Adding that, hold on.

Comment: ([wo]man) ;) you're welcome. also, just fyi, with $.post handling clicks on the submit button, you don't need a form action in your markup. I didn't suppress the default behavior, so you might need to do that.

Comment: Did you change anything? I just added it to my document, it looks the same.

Comment: Shall I just add same javascript for other unsubscribe form? and replace values of unsubscribe and subscribe?

Comment: Yes, I added the .attr('name','Subscribe') and .attr('name':'Unsubscribe'). Follow my original instructions. Do not add the javascript again, and do not include the second form. The code binds the mouse "click" event to the submit button, and the event handler is the .post() method. When the .post() method handles an event, it submits the serialized (json!) data to the url, and if it succeeds, it has a callback function that switches the button's name and value. This example is very simple, I commented each stage to help you understand. Read each line of code and consider what it's for :)

Comment: Oh, yeh I didn't notice, uff I really need to get into this stuff.. Thanx again ))

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want to have a JavaScript function like this:

```
function subscribe(id)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for real browsers
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for abominations
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
    document.getElementById("subscribeStatus").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","blog.php?id="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Call it and pass it the variable (id) you want with a button like this on the frontend.

```
<input type="button" name="click" value="Subscribe" onmousedown="subscribe(document.getElementById('id').value);">
```

Embed the user's ID as a hidden form field with id = "id" (or whatever).

Then on the PHP side (blog.php) just handle it with `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. And duplicate it for unsubscribe or find a way to work it together using a switch (or if) statement.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh yeah and subscribeStatus can be an HTML blank div on the frontend where you echo out "You've subscribed!" when the user clicks it. And using that you can do the neato subscribe/unsubscribe button switch then. But remember: You're asking for like 10 different things. Try to split them up.

Comment: so change form method to get, add provided javascript and onmousedown event to inputs right? I don't understand what you mean by hidden formfield, coukd you explain it pleas? ;)

Comment: Also: If you don't understand JavaScript well enough to do simple AJAX requests, you shouldn't seek jQuery-based solutions. Learn JS well enough, then use jQuery as needed. It's not the other way around.

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id;?>'>` is a hidden form field.